# Do "python3" and "python" use different path variables?

Tags: python, python3

The command `python` opens a Python 2.7.6 environment. If I want to interpret a Python 3 script, I need to rewrite the command to `python3`.

I've just installed the *numpy* package. In order to test the successful installation, I run the command `import numpy`. It works well when using the `python` command. However, `python3` does not find the package.

How is this possible? Do these two commands use different *path* variables? How can I change the behavior?

Comment: might be related/useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53767029/52074

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're absolutely right, they use different [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH)s.

You can think of Python 2.x and Python 3.x as completely different programming environments. And yes, they store their packages in different locations.

To get numpy working, you can type:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-numpy
```

If you want to find out where exactly a package is kept, you can look at the module objects `__path__` attribute:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.__path__
['/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy']
```

You can also install `python3-pip` and then run `pip3 install whatever` to install packages for Python 3 with [Pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/), for packages that aren't available in Ubuntu as `python3-whatever`.

In case you're confused about the difference between distutils, setuptools, easy_install, pip and the rest, use pip. That's the cool one. :)

Comment: They don't use different PYTHONPATH, but rather python2 uses only packages in the $PREFIX/lib/python2*and python3 only those in $PREFIX/lib/python3*.

Answer (score 5):

No, they use the same `PATH`. However, *this* problem isn't with the `PATH`.

Python 2 and Python 3 are sufficiently different that packages have to be written separately for both of them. You cannot use a package written for one with the other.

In Ubuntu, these modules are stored in different locations and are packaged separately - [`python-numpy`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python-numpy) for Python 2, [`python3-numpy`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python3-numpy) for Python 3. If you want numpy with Python 3, install `python3-numpy`.

```
$ python3 -c 'import sys; print (sys.path)'
['', '/usr/lib/python3.4', '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload', '/home/muru/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
$ python2 -c 'import sys; print (sys.path)'
['', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client']
```

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, both are importing modules from different locations:

- Python2.7: `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/`
- Python3.x:  `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/`

To be able to import `numpy` with both interpreters, be sure to install their corresponding packages:

- Python2.7: `sudo apt-get install python-numpy`
- Python3.x:  `sudo apt-get install python3-numpy`